# How can I import the 'M' variable in angular testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, materialize

I defined a variable 'M' in typings.d.ts, in order to be able to use materialize css. But at testing I get a 'M' is not defined error.

I have imported 'typings.d.ts' in tsconfig.json under "typeRoots" and also in karma.conf.js under "files", but this does not work.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "materialize-css",
      "jest",
      "typings"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/typings.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    files: ["src/typings.d.ts"],
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

typings.d.ts:

```
declare var M;
```

Comment: try this:   files: [
      {pattern: './src/typings.d.ts', watched: false}
    ],

Comment: No it does not work.